# Android fit image to imageview without preserving aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to fit image to android imageview **without** preserving the aspect ratio. I.e. I want the image to resize to imageview's size. I know that I can use the image as a background of the imageview to achieve the purpose. But is there any way I can use it as a foreground image of the imageview and fitting it to its dimension?

I have seen various answers and all of them suggest the other thing(image view fitting to the image size).I want to do it via xml.

Comment: Of course, you have tried `android:scaleType="fitXY"`, I suppose... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: @BobMalooga great! Thank you. It works for me. You can give this as the answer! I am surprised that I could not find a matching answer/hint on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you have tried

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

I suppose...

[Developer - Scale Type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

This would scale in both directions (X, Y) independently 
*(by using the FILL algorhithm, which is - more or less, the same as what it does when setting a background)*.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Works like a gem! Just hyperlinked that developer.android.com link as an edit.

Comment: I'm happy to contribute. Now, may I know what's wrong in using the background? Just for curiosity - you might answer: "I use the background and the src is semitransparent (or has transparent parts)"